# Adding multiple id's to url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, parameters

In my react app, i have a tags input and a list of tags, each tag has an id and what I'm doing is when the user chooses any of tags I'm taking it's id and adding it to a url as a param, the thing is that i want to have this param multiple times, but the issue I'm facing is when i add a new one the old one gets removed, here is the code:

```
handleAddition(tag) {
    this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));

    let url = new URL('https://myapp.com/subjects');
    url.searchParams.append("tags", `${tag.id}`);
    let requestUrl = url.toString();

    axios
      .get(`${requestUrl}`, { headers })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(success)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The old tag gets removed because you keep creating new url.
You can do this by either keep appending tag with existing url, make sure the url is the newest or append all the tags altogether, something like:

```
handleAddition(tag) {
    this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));

    let url = new URL('https://myapp.com/subjects');
    this.state.tags.forEach(tag => {
    url.searchParams.append("tags", `${url.searchParams.get('tags')}, ${tag.id}`);
    }
    let requestUrl = url.toString();
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
let url = new URL('https://myapp.com/subjects');
url.searchParams.append("tags", `${tag.id}`);
```

You are assigning a URL parameter called `tags` but you can only do this once for a single value.  You can comma separated this, however you will need to use the `useState` callback to the asynchronous nature of assigning state, as you can't assume that `this.state.tags` will be updated after `setState` is invoked.

```
this.setState(state => {
   const tags = [...state.tags, tag];

   let url = new URL('https://myapp.com/subjects');
   url.searchParams.append("tags", tags.join(','));
   let requestUrl = url.toString();

   axios
     .get(requestUrl, { headers })
     .then(response => {
        console.log(success)
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
     });

   return { tags };
});
```